# Objective-C array of u_int8_t in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, primitive-types

i need to convert in Swift lots of Objective-C code.
One of this is an array of (u_int8_t) created by cinese engineer

```
u_int8_t blankBytes[] = {0x1b, '*', 'r', 'Y', '0', '0', '0', 0x00};
```

I tried to do it by converting each chars to UInt8:

```
let blankBytes: [UInt8] = [
    0x1b,
    UInt8("*"),
    UInt8("r"),
    UInt8("Y"),
    UInt8("1"),
    UInt8("0"),
    UInt8("0"),
    UInt8("0"),
    0x00
]
```

But "*", and the other chars, cannot be converted into UInt8.

Anyone can help me?
I'm also searching for a primitive-types guide in Swift.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
let blankBytes: [UInt8] = [
    0x1b,
    UInt8(ascii: "*"),
    UInt8(ascii: "r"),
    UInt8(ascii: "Y"),
    UInt8(ascii: "1"),
    UInt8(ascii: "0"),
    UInt8(ascii: "0"),
    UInt8(ascii: "0"),
    0x00
]
```

The reference for Swift types can be found here: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014608

**EDIT:**
Thanks to the comment from Kametrixom, you can save a step by omitting the unnecessary initialization of a UnicodeScalar. The code above has been updated.

Comment: You don't actually need to initialise `UnicodeScalar` yourself, you can just do `UInt8(ascii: "*")` because `"*"` is a `UnicodeScalarLiteral`

Comment: I thought I tried that and it didn't work, but I just tried again, and sure enough you are right.